# How to set edge style on UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, captions

I'm working on adding custom captions to my iOS app that plays videos. I'd like to support all the features of CEA-708 (which are essentially rich-text captions), but I can't figure out how to apply the necessary edge-styles using a UILabel.

The image below shows the edge styles I want to support. However, I am struggling to find a way to achieve raised/depressed edges. Any ideas?

[image: CEA-708 caption font edge styles]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that those behaviors are expected in iOS. The only idea that I can suggest is to use two labels to achieve those effects, with different z-indexes and positions and colors to obtain the offset similar to the edge.
Otherwise, you can try to take a look to this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just using drop shadows with various offsets, rather than doing anything fancy.